# MySQL how to find host and user info?

Tags: mysql

how do I find out what my database hostname and user login is? I've tried localhost and root@localhost but no success.

> Failed to connect to database host.domain.com:3306 user:root. Please
>   check the database settings you provided and verify that MySQL is up
>   and running.

Comment: Ask the person or company who is providing your mySQL database.

Comment: If it was a login issue, you'd get permission denied. Do as the error says and make sure that MySQL is running, and that it's accessible via TCP - default installation allows only local unix-domain connections.

Comment: @Pekka I'd like to learn how to find out myself. I have root access

Comment: @MarcB I'm installing a script/mod that requires access to mysql is there something I can type with the mysql command? i've checked the my.cnf file and it only has 3 line within it.

Comment: Is the mysql daemon actually running on your server? SSH into the server and type `service mysqld start`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that mysql is running and you have credentials that work, you can get all the host and user information from the mysql database once you are running mysql successfully - "select User,Host from mysql.user" for example.

But, it looks like your problem is that you can't log into mysql.

If you don't have a valid credentials to your own database, one has to wonder how you managed to lose them. That happens, however, and the way to reset those credentials is described in detail at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html.